# How to post from iOS App to Facebook and Twitter wall

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, sharekit

I have succesfully integrated Sharekit in my application.All I want is to post One image with a description of my app to facebook and twitter wall.
I am able to get it in twitter but i am facing a problem with facebook.I am getting a page with saying The iOS bundle ID is missing from app's Facebook iOS settings.and i am struck there.the page also says you have already authorised App.press Okay to continue.and that Okay is directing to a blank page.

Comment: which iOS will be the base? if you will set it to iOS 6 you can use the native sharers, if not you will need the facebook sdk or sharekit

Comment: base sdk is 6.0 and deployment target is 4.3

Comment: Also can u give me any links on how to use those native sharers you are talking about

Comment: deployment target have to be >= 6.0 to use native facebook share, and >= 5.0 to use native twitter share

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post in facebook using ShareKit, You can do this using FBConnect, check the below link

> [github sample code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

Comment: Sharekit is under correction, for facebook, need to be reviewed

Comment: so whats the use of facebook option in sharekit?

Comment: hey, currently several issues are being reported about sharekit, it happens. because facebook keeps on changing APi frequently. You can do it yourselves using fbconnect, especially post text is simple one

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-register your App at developer.facebook.com
And then, when you'll have generated appId, type it in shareKit settings file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [SLComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). [Check out this tutorial: How to use inbuilt Facebook/Twitter API in iOS6.](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.ca/2012/07/tutorial-how-to-use-inbuilt.html)